# Error checking in Java: S to Start and Q to Quit

Tags: java, error-handling, iteration, conditional-statements, error-checking

I'm a student currently taking basic Java classes.
I'm working on a code that asks the user an input for a game to "start" and to "quit". Sooo I chose the string "S" and "Q" respectively. If the user enters S, the game proceeds. If the user enters Q, the program displays "Thanks for playing" or something. If the user enters something other than S and Q, the program asks again until it gets a valid input. I *almost* got everything correctly except for the error checking part. Any possible suggestions to fix my code?

Thank you in advance! :)

(partial code)

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    boolean game = false;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Game! ");
    System.out.println("Press S to Start or Q to Quit");

    userInput = scan.nextLine();

    if (userInput.equals("S")){
        game = true;
    } else if (userInput.equals("Q")){
        game = false;
    } else {
        do {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Enter a valid input: ");
            userInput = scan.nextLine();
        } while (!"S".equals(userInput)) || (!"Q".equals(userInput)); // I'm not sure if this is valid???
    }

    if (userInput.equals("S")){
        ///// Insert main code for the game here////
    } else if (userInput.equals("Q")){
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an infinite loop:

```
while (!"S".equals(userInput)) || (!"Q".equals(userInput)); // always true
```

For this condition to **not** hold you'll need an input that is equal to `"S"` **and** to `"Q"` together. It's easy to see applying [De-Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
while (!("S".equals(userInput)) && "Q".equals(userInput))); // always true
```

Obviously, it won't happen.

You probably want:

```
while (!"S".equals(userInput)) && (!"Q".equals(userInput));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't vote on answers yet, but the prior one is correct.

Breaking out the logic:

```
input = "Z"
while( !(S==Z) || !(Q==Z) ) -> while( !(F) || !(F) ) -> while( T || T ) -> repeat

input = "Q"
while( !(S==Q) || !(Q==Q) ) -> while( !(F) || !(T) ) -> while( T || F ) -> repeat
```

Switching to "and" makes case #2 work.
Do you do anything with your "game" boolean? If the user enters the while loop then the boolean will always be false.